# WPF DataGrid - Align Column with Autogenerated Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid bounded to a DataSet; Columns are autogenerated.
I need to align number columns to the right. I can use a Converter, like in this example I found on the web:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col}" Header="Col" Width="200">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment" Value="{Binding Col, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

But in my case the column are autogenerated, so I can't use

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
```

And I don't know how to bind the property

```
<Setter Property="TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment" Value="{Binding Col, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be an ideal solution, but you could try and set the ElementStyle for each column after they have been generated by hooking a handler to `AutoGeneratedColumns` event.

This is what I tried:

**Style**

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="ColumnStyle">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource AlignmentConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

**XAML for DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          AutoGeneratedColumns="Dg_OnAutoGeneratedColumns" 
          SelectionMode="Extended"/>
```

**EventHandler Code (Code Behind)**

```
void Dg_OnAutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var dataGridColumn in dg.Columns)
    {
        var textColumn = dataGridColumn as DataGridTextColumn;
        if (textColumn == null) continue;

        textColumn.ElementStyle = FindResource("ColumnStyle") as Style;
    }
}
```

If you do not like Code Behind, then you can always create an attached behavior to achieve the same result.